# I would like to test a php method xy which have php function die(), how can I do this?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a method like this:

```
public function xy()
{
 die('script was terminated.')
}
```

If it possible to test this method with phpUnit?

Comment: Probably not (easily). PHPUnit will not be able to distinguish that method's `die()` from a real `die()`, and will, well, just `die()`.

Comment: Instead you would need to wrap the `die()` in some other function that takes a different action if run inside a test.

Comment: If your function "xy" just do a die(), then I would simply create a mock and then I would assert if that function was called.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by overloading the die() function. How you do this is described here:
[Intercepting the Exit Statement](https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers)

Simply calling it is not possible as there is only one PHPUnit process and you will kill it by calling die() or exit().

Also have look at the answers to this question:
[How do you use PHPUnit to test a function if that function is supposed to kill PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347794/how-do-you-use-phpunit-to-test-a-function-if-that-function-is-supposed-to-kill-p)